# iOS Reachability when app is in Background

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, reachability

My application requires exact information on whether or not user is connected to Wifi network and not on internet connectivity so do not comment on the use case please. The task is: user needs to verify that their Wifi is connected but if they dont have any Wifi network available to connect to, they can do it later. For this I need my app to notify the user when he later connects to a Wifi network that now you can continue with the test.

Can I accomplish this using Reachability in background fetch request? Are there any limitations to tasks that app can perform in Background fetching?

Comment: Why not just check on launch of the app?

Comment: Please read the Task. I am already doing it when app is in the foreground. I need a way to do that when app is not active.

Comment: Yes you can use reachability in the background.

Answer (score 0):

This is not solvable in the general case. You cannot run arbitrary code in the background for an indefinite period of time (unless you already are an allowed background task for other reasons, such as location services or VoIP, but these still have restrictions). And you cannot request to be launched when reachability changes.

You can, however, configure an `NSURLRequest` to not use cellular access. That's not exactly the same as "wireless" but it's close and may be what you actually mean (you're not clear on why "wireless" is the criteria). You can then use `NSURLSessionUploadTask` or `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` to ask the OS to perform the action when possible (without waking you up or involving you in any way when you're in the background). If that request were to your server, you could then use a push notification to alert the user and achieve the experience you're describing.